# Find $a$ and $b$ such that $a-b=c$ and the geometric mean of $a$ and $b$ is $m$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given $m,c\in\mathbb{R}^+$, how can I find numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a-b=c$ and $m = e^\frac{\ln(a)+\ln(b)}{2}$ (i.e., $m$ is the geometric mean of $a$ and $b$).  I understand that this doesn't work for all $c$, so no need to explain that.

Comment: Why don't you just write $m=\sqrt{ab\,{}}$? $\qquad$

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I'm used to thinking about geometric mean as the back-transformed arithmetic mean on the log scale but I see that this is not helpful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $a-b=c$ we get $a=b+c$. From $m$ the geometric mean of $a$ and $b$ we get

$$ab=m^2$$
$$(b+c)b=m^2$$
$$b^2+cb-m^2=0$$
$$b=\frac{-c\pm\sqrt{c^2+4m^2}}{2}$$

The geometric mean is usually defined only for positive numbers, so we take

$$b=\frac{-c+\sqrt{c^2+4m^2}}{2}$$
and thus

$$a=\frac{c+\sqrt{c^2+4m^2}}{2}$$

If you do accept a geometric mean of negative numbers (with a positive geometric mean), you can get another solution by using the negative square root in those expressions. Or, instead of that $a$ and $b$ you can use $-b$ and $-a$.

Answer (score 2):

Using the equations $$\sqrt{ab}=m$$ $$a-b=c,$$

you can arrive at $ab=m^2$ and $b=a-c$. Substitution gives you a quadratic in $a$ that can be solved for certain $c$.